# Why indexed access type using generics resolves to intersection?

Tags: typescript

In one of the vidoes the author noted that here:

```
interface MyMouseEvent {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

interface MyKeyboardEvent {
  key: string;
}

interface MyEventObjects {
  click: MyMouseEvent;
  keypress: MyKeyboardEvent;
}

function handleEvent<K extends keyof MyEventObjects>(
  eventName: K,
  callback: (e: MyEventObjects[K]) => void
) {
  if (eventName === 'click') {
    callback({ x: 0, y: 0 }); // ERROR
  } else if (eventName === 'keypress') {
    callback({ key: 'Enter' }); // ERROR
  }
}
```

The type of `e` parameter is resolved as `MyMouseEvent & MyKeyboardEvent`.
IMHO this is true, if you hover the error it says:

> Type '{ x: number; y: number; }' is not assignable to type
> 'MyMouseEvent & MyKeyboardEvent'

Then he also noted that if we had defined the callback in following way for example:

```
  ....
  callback: (e: MyEventObjects[keyof MyEventObjects]) => void
```

Then type of `e` becomes  `MyMouseEvent | MyKeyboardEvent`; this wasn't suggested as solution if I remember correctly, it was just observation.

Does someone have explanation why is type of `e` different (intersection in one case, and union in another) depending if we used `MyEventObjects[K]` vs `MyEventObjects[keyof MyEventObjects]`?

Comment: `K` and `keyof MyEventObjects` are very different things. While the latter is a union of the keys of `MyEventObjects`, `K` is only *constrained* to be the keys of `MyEventObjects`. The *caller* of the function determines the concrete type of `K`. Until then, `K` is just a placeholder which can be used in multiple places to represent relations between their types. When you write `MyEventObjects[keyof MyEventObjects]`, this can be evaluated on the spot leading to the union you described in your question. But `MyEventObjects[K]` can not be evaluated yet.

Comment: @TobiasS. @TobiasS. So you are saying if say `keyof MyEventObjects` is `"a"|"b"`, then it could be `K` is `"a"`, and if we had type `MyEventObjects[K]` somewhere and we resolved it to `MyEventObjects["a"|"b"]` by default (as we do with `keyof`), it would be wrong, when `K = "a"`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It seems like TypeScript expands `(e: MyEventObjects[K]) => void` to `(e: MyMouseEvent) => void | (e: MyKeyboardEvent) => void` leading to the intersection because `MyEventObjects[K]` is in a contra variant position.

Comment: @TobiasS. Yes, this short comment sadly doesn't explain the full picture to me. I am having similar discussion with Jared below.

Comment: I wrote a (much) longer answer, let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The example doesn't work because Typescript can't narrow the type of the `callback` parameter based on the value of the `eventName` parameter. The only way that `callback` can be safely called is with an argument that satisfies *both* of its possible parameter types.

---

If you *intersect* function types you get one function with a parameter type that is the *union* of the two input functions' parameter types, and vice versa.

For example, intersecting these two functions types:

```
type A = (arg: string) => void;
type B = (arg: number) => void;

type C = A & B;
```

results in type `C` that is equivalent to `type C = (arg: string | number) => void`.

Similarly, if you union the types (`type C = A | B;`) then you would get `type C = (arg: string & number) => void` (or, in this case, `(arg: never) => void`, because the compiler has worked out that no value can be both a `string` and a `number` at the same time.

---

It's not obvious but writing

```
callback: (e: MyEventObjects[K]) => void
```

is the same as writing

```
callback: ((e: MyEventObjects['click']) => void) | ((e: MyEventObjects['keypress']) => void)
```

which, from my previous edit about contravariance, is the same as

```
callback: (e: MyEventObjects['click'] & MyEventObjects['keypress']) => void
```

That's where the union and intersection come in: from the unconstrained `K` key. I know that your code does constrain it with the if-statement, but that's where my earlier point about narrowing comes in; Typescript doesn't know that `K` has been constrained at this point.

Comment: I think there are two typos: "For example, *unioning* these two functions types..." refers to type C which is A & B, should not it say *intersecting* instead of *unioning* then? Similarly it says *intersected* here: "Similarly, if you intersected (type C = A | B;)", but type C refers to *union* A|B.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Good spot! I seem to remember changing the code before I posted it but not the wording... I'll edit it for future posterity.

Answer (score 1):

There's some preliminary ground to cover here, let's (re)define some basic stuff from your question:

```
interface MyMouseEvent {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

interface MyKeyboardEvent {
  key: string;
}

const m: MyMouseEvent = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const k: MyKeyboardEvent = { key: 'a' };

type EventMapping = {
  'keypress': MyKeyboardEvent;
  'click': MyMouseEvent;
}
type EventKeys = keyof EventMapping; // 'keypress' | 'click'
```

and your question is about the difference between these two functions:

```
function handleEvent<K extends EventKeys>(
  eventName: K,
  callback: (e: EventMapping[K]) => void
) {
  if (eventName === 'click') {
    callback(m); // ERROR
  } else if (eventName === 'keypress') {
    callback(k); // ERROR
  }
}

function handleEvent2<K extends EventKeys>(
  eventName: K,
  callback: (e: EventMapping[EventKeys]) => void
) {
  if (eventName === 'click') {
    callback(m); // Fine
  } else if (eventName === 'keypress') {
    callback(k); // Fine
  }
}
```

and why Typescript lets you narrow in one case but not the other. The problem is that the type of the callback parameter is completely different:

```
handleEvent('click', (e: MyMouseEvent) => {});  // Fine
handleEvent2('click', (e: MyMouseEvent) => {}); // ERROR
```

> Argument of type '(e: MyMouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(e: MyMouseEvent | MyKeyboardEvent) => void'

Which means that `callback` has a different type in the first case. So what is it?

```
handleEvent('click', undefined);
```

> Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(e: MyMouseEvent) => void'

Depending on the concrete `K` we pass, the type will either be `(e: MyMouseEvent) => void` *or* `(e: MyKeyboardEvent) => void`. In other words, the type of `callback` is: `(e: MyMouseEvent) => void | (e: MyKeyboardEvent) => void`, and this *varies generically with K*.

But in the second case that isn't so. There's no generic: the `callback` parameter's argument is just the straight up union we get from indexing a mapping type with the union of its keys: `(e: MyMouseEvent | MyKeyboardEvent) => void`.

Now it's clear to see that they aren't the same type at all:
`(x: A | B) => void` **does not** equal `(x: A) => void | (x: B) => void`. For convenience going forward, let's call these `F(A | B)` and `FA | FB` respectively. Remember `FA` and `FB` are the actual functions we want to pass.

### Wait, Where'd that intersection come from?

Let's say from the above realizations that callback must be a function `F` with a generic parameter `T` that extends `A | B` which we'll call `U` for short. Functions in Typescript are covariant in their parameters, and from the definition of covariance we know that if `T extends U`, then `F<T & U> = F<T> | F<U>`. Let's now go back through and remove the substitutions: `callback<Event extends A | B> = callback<A> | callback<B>` hence intersection: `callback<A> | callback<B> = callback<A & B>`. It's a little hard to see in the code, because this generic parameter is the index on the mapped type rather than explicitly the event/union of events. But remember we can answer the question by thinking about what we can actually pass to `handleEvent` and it's clear that it varies based on the generic `K`.

### But wait, doesn't the second version of `handleEvent` vary the same way?

No.

There is no generic variance in the second version. Note also that it's *wrong*: you're not actually narrowing the type.

```
function handleEvent2<K extends EventKeys>(
  eventName: K,
  callback: (e: EventMapping[EventKeys]) => void
) {
  callback(k);
  callback(m);
  // look ma, no narrowing, no errors!
}
```

For any function `F` that has a non-generic parameter type `A | B` we can pass it either `A` or `B`: it's up to `F` to narrow it.

But this means, since `callback`'s type is now `F(A | B)` and not `FA | FB` that the only thing you can pass to it is `(e: MyKeyboardEvent | MyMouseEvent) => void` which isn't what you want at all: you want to pass it a *specific* variant like `FA` determined generically by `K`.

### OK I get it, how do I fix it?

By not passing concrete values to a function that expects a generic. Either of these variations will work:

```
function handleEvent3<K extends EventKeys>(
  eventName: K,
  callback: (e: EventMapping[K]) => void,
  event: EventMapping[K]
) {
  callback(event);
}

function handleEvent4<K extends EventKeys>(
  eventName: K,
  callback: (e: EventMapping[K]) => void,
) {
  return function (event: EventMapping[K]) {
    callback(event);
  }
}
```